# C++ Weird Variable Issues

Tags: c++, int

I'm using the following code to calculate and display the final score for a math game in C++.

```
int score = (correctNumber / 3) * 100;
cout << score;
```

The variable "correctNumber" is always a value between 0 and 3. However, unless "correctNumber" = 3, then the variable "score" always equals "0". When "correctNumber" equals 3 then "score" equals 100.

Say "correctNumber" was equal to 2. Shouldn't "score" be 67 then? Is this some issue with int variable type being unable to calculate decimal points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing math as integer so 1 / 3 is 0.

Try:

```
int score = (100 * correctNumber) / 3
```

and if you want to round:

```
int score = (100 * correctNumber + 1) / 3
```

Comment: (100 * 1 + 1) / 3 = 33.666667 which rounds to 34

Comment: hmmm...it comes out as 33 when I run it. Does C++ always round down?

Comment: Arithmetic with integers means only getting the integer part in the result but also on the intermediate computations. This is know as **truncation**. So, if you actually want to _round_ the result (at the end) it is recommended using `float` or `double` and finally invoking a _rounding_ method. My proposed solutions if for a question of efficiency for your specific scenario.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming `correctNumber` is an `int`, based on what you described. What's happening is **integer truncation**. When you divide an `int` by an `int`, the result always rounds down:

```
1/3 = 0.3333 = 0 as an integer
2/3 = 0.6667 = 0 as an integer
3/3 = 1.0000 = 1 as an integer
```

The easy way to remedy this here is to multiply it first:

```
int score = correctNumber * 100 / 3;
```

However, this still leaves you with 66 for 2, not 67. A clear and simple way of dealing with that (and many other rounding situations, though the rounding style is unconfigurable) is `std::round`, included since C++11:

```
int score = std::round(currentNumber * 100. / 3);
```

In the example, the dot in `100.` makes `100` a `double` (it's the same thing as `100.0`), so the result of the operation will be the floating-point value you want, not a pre-truncated value passed in as a floating-point value. That means you'll end up with 66.66666... going into `std::round` instead of 66.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct. `int` can't store real numbers.

But you can multiply first, and then divide, like

```
score = correctNumber * 100 / 3;
```

score will have 0, 33, 66, 100, depending on values of `correctNumber`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `(correctNumber / 3)` is an integer, so you can't get 0.666 or any fraction to multiply by 100, which what I believe is you want.

You could try to force it to be a `float` like this:

```
int score = ((float)correctNumber / 3) * 100;
```

This, however, will give you 66 instead of 67, cause it doesn't round up. You could use C99 `round()` for that.

```
int score = round(((float)correctNumber / 3) * 100);
```

UPDATE:

You can also use `+ 0.5` to round, like this:

```
int score = (correctNumber / 3.0f) * 100.0f + 0.5f;
```

Comment: I did so but Visual Studio is telling me that "identifier round is undefined."

Comment: @codedude it is part of C99, you can see by using gcc/g++. Without it you can use the old `+ 0.5`, I will update the answer.